# Приведение типов при использовании дженериков

Tags: java, generics

Ниже пример кода, где происходит не совсем понятные вещи, связанные с преобразованиями при использовании дженериков. Есть два класса, один наследует другой (А и B). Так же есть обобщенный метод (f1). Методу сообщаем, что хотим, что бы он возвращал объекты типа B. В методе создаем новый объект класса А и пытаемся его преобразовать типу B. Судя по всему это не получается, но ошибки не генерируется. Более того, объект типа A возвращается из метода f1() так же без ошибок, хотя А для B
является предком, а не потомком. Ошибка происходит в момент попытки присвоить указателю B b результаты выполнения f1()

1. Когда у f1, поменялся тип выходных данных? Был назначен тип B, но объект класса А успешно смог быть возвращен. Т.к. В потомок А, а не наоборот, то это явно не полиморфизм.
2. Почему преобразование T t = (T) new A();  не выдало ошибок? Оно же не произошло.

```
public class Main
{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main = new Main();
  B b = main.<B>f1();
 }

 public <T> T f1(){
  T t = (T) new A();
  System.out.println(t instanceof B); //false
  return t;
 } 

}

class A {

}

class B extends A{

}
```

Comment: &lt и &gt соответвтвенно для < >

Comment: по факту в вашем примере T это Object, поэтому кастование к дженерику, которые вы делаете ( T t = (T) new A(); ) является кастованием созданного экземпляра класса A к Object, а с этим проблем нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Когда у f1, поменялся тип выходных данных? Был назначен тип B, но объект класса А успешно смог быть возвращен. Т.к. В потомок А, а не наоборот, то это явно не полиморфизм**. -

> Полиморфизм — это способность обьекта использовать методы производного
> класса, который не существует на момент создания базового.

**Так же есть обобщенный метод (f1). Методу сообщаем, что хотим, что бы он возвращал объекты типа B** - шо значит у вас обобщенный метод? В java могут существовать методы c одинаковым наименованием но различный по параметрам. Так что у вас не получится иметь один метод на все случаи жизни.

2. **Почему преобразование T t = (T) new A(); не выдало ошибок? Оно же не произошло.** - Это явное преобразование, вы не получите ошибку во время компиляции.